# Scanner cant read/incorrectly reading my input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a code whereby I have to input people's name and money value. However I have used a scanner but it does not read the name that I input into the console. Whatever name I put, the code will tell me that no such name is found. I have tried for many hours trying to resolve this, assistance would be appreciated! (there are 6 total cases but I only posted the first one since its the only one I'm having problems with)
The code is as such:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    Change[] changeArray = new Change [10];
    int  numNames  = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter at least 10 records to test the program");
    String name = "";
    int change = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int[] totalNumberOfCoinsOf = {0,0,0,0,0};
    
    
    for (int i = 0;i < changeArray.length;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = reader.nextLine();
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter coin value for the person");
        change = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (change % 5 ==0) {
            break;
        }else if (change % 5 <2.5) {//round down to nearest 5 if change is less than 2.5
        change = change - change %5;
        break;
        }
        else if (change %5>=2.5)
        { 
        change = Math.round(change * 100)/100; //round up to nearest 5 if change is more than 2.5
        }

        
            
        }while (true);
        changeArray[i] = new Change(name, change);
        numNames++;
        do {System.out.println("Do you have another person to enter? (Y/N) ");
        String choice  = reader.nextLine();
        if (i!=changeArray.length - 1) {
            if(choice.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
                break;
            }else if (choice.toUpperCase().equals("N")) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }while(true);
        if (flag==1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    do {
        System.out.println("\n[1] Search by name ");
        System.out.println("\n[2] Search largest coin");
        System.out.println("\n[3] Search smallest coin");
        System.out.println("\n[4] Total coins");
        System.out.println("\n[5] Sum of coins");
        System.out.println("\n[6] Exit the program");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        int  choice  = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        
        switch (choice) {
        case  1:
            System.out.print("Enter name to search: ");
            name = reader.nextLine();
            flag = 0;
            
            for (int i = 0;i < numNames; i++) {
                if (name.equals(changeArray[i].getName())) {
                    System.out.println("Customer: ");
                    System.out.println(changeArray[i].getName() + " " + changeArray[i].getCoinChangeAmount());
                    int[] coins = changeArray[i].getChange();
                    System.out.println("Change: ");
                    if(coins[0]!=0) {
                        System.out.println("Dollar coins: "+coins[0]);
                    }
                    if(coins[1]!=0) {
                        System.out.println("50  cents: "+coins[1]);
                    }
                    if(coins[2]!=0) {
                        System.out.println("25  cents: "+coins[2]);
                    }
                    if(coins[3]!=0) {
                        System.out.println("10  cents: "+coins[3]);
                    }
                    if(coins[4]!=0) {
                        System.out.println("5  cents: "+coins[4]);
                    }
                    flag++;
                    
                }
            }
            
            if (flag==0) {
                System.out.println("Name: "+name);
                System.out.println("Not found! ");
            }
            break;
```

//Change class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Change {

```
private String name;
private int coinChangeAmount;

public Change() {
    this.name = "no name";
    this.coinChangeAmount = 0;
    
}

public Change(String name, int coinChangeAmount) {
    this.name = "name";
    this.coinChangeAmount = coinChangeAmount;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCoinChangeAmount() {
    return coinChangeAmount;
}
```

Comment: Since the problem is that `name.equals(changeArray[i].getName())` is always `false`, my best guess is that there’s a problem with `getName`. Maybe you forgot the `return`?

Comment: Hi! Appreciate the reply. However I've checked that the return is already inputted in the code

Comment: As @Ryan1729 already mentioned it seems like an issue within that `if` condition. Provide`Change` class implementation, so that others can verify it?

Comment: edited the Change class into the post

Comment: @EstStacker Look at your parameterized  constructor. ```this.name = "name" ```, silly mistake I say

Comment: The java language was designed from the ground up with great debugging support. If you debug your program, by setting a break point in your code using your IDE and stepping through your code, I'm sure yo'll find the problem. It's an essential skill to learn.

Comment: @Sayam Bhattacharya Oh my god, thank you for pointing that out. I've tested after changing and it works! To think that I've been trying to resolve this for hours

Comment: @user16320675 it was a work in progress haha, i fixed it already